# Is it practical to become an airline pilot in order to travel internationally?

Tags: commercial-aviation, career

I am a person with very diverse interests and a lot of life goals I want to achieve. One of them is becoming an airline pilot (just working as one for a year or two) and the other is traveling the world.

I would like to combine two goals in one, that is becoming an airline pilot after I finish college and travelling the world at the same time, i.e. flying intercontinental flights.

So, my question is basically this: **Is it possible to learn to fly and become an airline pilot within about 3 years (let's say age 20-23), then immediately get employed as an airline pilot and fly intercontinental routes (even as a co-pilot)?**

Comment: All the long haul commercial pilots I know spent upwards of 6 years flying small craft, instructing, taking low paid jobs at small flying clubs and working their way up through local and regional airlines, to eventually reaching flight crew on long haul international carriers. The answer is going to be a big No unless you have some incredible source of funds to make this happen!

Comment: `becoming an airline pilot (just working as one for a year or two)` - you're going to spend a large amount of money and spend many years training and progressing to do something for a year or two?  To answer your question, no.  It takes around 10 years to even get into the right hand seat of international flights.

Comment: +1, since after all this is a valid question, that deserves a good answer for future searches and reference.

Comment: Now it could be interesting to understand what is the life of long haul crew members, and whether they have time to visit the country they land in during their legal rest time.

Comment: Do you know for sure that you aren't affected by [airsickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airsickness)? A friend of mine grew up with the idea of becoming a (military) pilot, chose to study in a highschool 1 hour away in bus for this reason, worked hard to enter Italian aviation... only to find out in the first three months of training that he simply couldn't handle flying an aircraft (yes he did fly on aircrafts before, but not as a pilot). He ended up becoming an aereonautical engineer. (btw dyslexic too... so even from highschool he had to put a huge effort in all of this).

Comment: The only thing that can get you to travel internationally with minimal preparation is to be drafted for a war, but that has OBVIOUS risks.  Anything safe that takes you all over the world has checks and balances to prevent exactly this type of abuse (using a job to travel).

Comment: If you only want to be a pilot for one or two years, it is probably best to remove it of your bucket list and use the money you save by not investing in pilot training to travel the world.

Comment: @Nelson I taught English for a couple of years.  It is another way to travel internationally.  I am sure there are others.

Comment: To add to the list of alternatives, consider working on a cruise ship. It's a lot of work, but it's also kind of a non-stop party. You meet a lot of people, see some cool places, and it's generally great weather!

Comment: Interestingly, since you're a college student, studying is one viable way to travel. But it's not easy because the competition is fierce (there are more students than there are opportunities). A lot of countries have organisations that offer scholarships (or even the government itself). That would be the first thing to research. If that's not available then some universities also offer scholarships for foreign students. Finally, at the doctorate level, some research programs offer scholarship/sponsorships.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJk9Skxyi84

Comment: If you have a lot of diverse interests, I suggest picking one that has good, well-paid career prospects. Work at becoming really and well qualified at that one. Do the rest as hobbies. Earn enough money, and you can travel internationally, with time to see the places you visit.

Comment: If your goal is traveling the world, go teach English abroad. I know a few who did this - traveling abroad for several years, living in different countries gives you a "homebase" away from home to more easily explore the world. Many countries worldwide want people to do this.

Comment: If you don't get sea sick and don't have visible tattoos, come down to Fort Lauderdale and get a job on a private yacht. The yachts come here for refits between seasons. You can make $15 an hour cash cleaning bilges. If they like you they will offer to take you with them. If it is four stripes that you want, you can go training schools between seasons in the Med and Caribbean to take the licensing tests. Don't tell anyone you are not fully committed.

Comment: Have you considered joining the air force or navy? (The navy has pilots too.) You get all the flying and travel and the training is free. The downside is people shooting at you, of course.

Comment: If I had asked this question it would have been closed for being opinion-based.

Answer (score 67):

No, this is not a good idea, and No, it is not possible finish your education at 23, and then get employed as an intercontinental airline pilot.

It seems you have a distorted idea of what an airline pilot actually does. An intercontinental airline pilot usually spends just 24 hours at the layover destination. Much of that time is spent sleeping to recover from the fatigue of the long haul flight and sleeping to prepare for the next long haul flight. Not much time for sight-seeing.

The first requirement for becoming an airline pilot is a love of aviation and aircraft.  Most airline pilots today have been passionate about aviation since an early age.

You will never be successful unless you are passionate about aviation due to all the roadblocks and hardships you will have to overcome in order to reach your goal.

To say that you only want to do it for 1-2 years is proof enough that you don't have what it takes.

Comment: Lets also mention that for the first 1-2 years of your career, you're probably running a short shuttle route in the midwest.  No big jets, no international destintions.

Comment: @abelenky Not every aviation career is in the USA, you know.

Comment: @DavidRicherby or a given nation's equivalent of the boring midwest

Comment: @tac Well, most nations aren't big enough to have an equivalent of the boring Midwest. For example, in Europe, surely most commercial passenger pilots have to be on international flights. The countries aren't big enough to have a lot of internal flights and your one-hour Chicago to Omaha flight turns into a one-hour London to Frankfurt flight.

Comment: @DavidRicherby has a point. The percentage of domestic flights in the U.S. is quite unique to the U.S. That said, intra-Europe flights are mostly analogous to U.S. domestic flights, except that they do technically cross international borders (even if they might remain within the Schengen zone and not require immigration.) That said, there are some airlines that fly almost exclusively long-haul international, but these are mostly in Asia (e.g. Korean Air, Asiana, Cathay Pacific.) If you want a fast-track to long-haul intercontinental, you'd probably need to move there.

Comment: If you think there's no boring destinations in Europe, you've never been to the "airports" served by low-cost carriers like Ryanair. Look e.g. where their ["Frankfurt" Hahn airport is located.](https://goo.gl/maps/AiKoGbBiaBS2)

Comment: @DavidRicherby - why wouldn't the London to Frankfurt be just as boring as Chicago to Omaha?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that as a pilot, he will benefit from staff travel. While initially he may only be deployed on short flights, or may only have 24 hours on a layover, if he flies for a major airline he will be able to travel on the airlines long-haul flights for little more than the cost of taxes. This would allow him to travel the world for next to nothing on his days off.

Comment: Any employee of an airline gets "staff travel". You don't need to be a pilot.  Staff travel may get you to the destination relatively cheaply but you still have expenses once you arrive.  Many airline employees prefer purchasing airline tickets rather than be subject to the uncertainties of standby staff travel.

Comment: There is also the aspect of "ok, you're going to see the world - SFO to HND for the next two years."  While I admit unfamiliarity with the system, I doubt that one would be doing all the different routes.

Comment: @reirab There are hundreds of domestic flights within the UK.  It's not much different to the mid-West except most of the flights are shorter.  London-Aberdeen for example is a longer flight than Paris, Brussels, Amsterdam and dozens of other international destinations.  FOs spend most of their early years on domestic.

Comment: @Simon Yes, I'm aware of that, but it's nothing like the percentage (or quantity) in the U.S., which was all I was saying on that point. About 80% of airline passengers carried in the U.S. are on domestic flights. The percentage of domestic flights is probably 90%+. The percentage of long-haul is tiny. Most airline pilots in the U.S. spend _their entire career_ on domestic. My point was just that if you want a fast-track to flying long-haul, you'll need to go somewhere else, like SE Asia or maybe the Middle East, where a much higher percentage of flights are long-haul.

Comment: @reirab got it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 29):

Even once you get a job as a commercial pilot, you're not going to be starting intercontinental routes immediately.

For starters (in the US at least), you're probably only going to be able to start at a regional airline, flying short regional jet flights back and forth.

The airline industry is *very* much dependent on seniority, so you'll have to put in substantial time at that regional carrier before you have a chance at even getting hired by one of the big mainline airlines. Even once you do, the routes you fly on are bid based on seniority, so you're not going to get intercontinental routes for quite a while.

Also, don't forget that intercontinental flights are flown on different equipment than medium range mainline flights, which are different equipment from regional jets. you're going to have to get trained and certified for several different aircraft along the way.

So yes, if you become a pilot you may eventually be able to fly intercontinental routes and see the world, but it will likely take decades of work before you're in that position.

Comment: In the U.S., this is very true. You'll rarely see a young pilot flying intercontinental routes for U.S. carriers. That said, it's not true for the whole world. If you get a job at Cathay Pacific, for example, you'll be flying wide-bodies almost immediately.

Comment: Also, judging from a few aspiring airline pilots I've known, your first years may not be with airlines at all, but with freight companies doing runs between small towns to pick up & deliver for FexEx & UPS.   (In piston twins, or even singles.)

Answer (score 25):

If your intention is to travel the world, then don't be a pilot. **Instead, be a flight attendant**.

In addition to the possibility of being on international flights relatively early in your career, you will likely be surrounded by a majority of female coworkers who will be very glad to let you walk the aisles, lift the luggage, calm the rowdy passengers, and deal with the occasional butt-pincher.

Comment: Another tip is to work as a freight pilot. Airline pilots fly a small number of routes. The trips freight pilots make are much more diverse.

Comment: Hmm... At least for the case of the U.S., my understanding was that FAs had similar seniority situations to pilots, where it is mostly quite senior FAs on long-haul routes with junior FAs mostly stuck on regional routes. FAs also don't have the "move to Southeast Asia" fast-track option like pilots, unless perhaps they also happen to be young, attractive, and female.

Comment: @reirab Had a friend get picked up as a flight attendant by Hawaiian Airlines a few years back and he was telling stories of adventures in Southeast Asia early on. No college, no experience either.

Comment: @digitgopher Ah, yeah, I suppose Hawaiian would be an exception, since they have a much higher percentage of long-haul routes than other U.S. airlines (because nearly everything is long-haul from Hawaii, except the other Hawaiian islands.)

Answer (score 20):

"...a year or two"? Seriously don't even think about it. But ignoring your lack of commitment, here are some ideas.

Instead of traveling the world, try living and working in a foreign country. This can be an incredible adventure and broaden your horizons. You'll have an understanding and appreciation for international concerns that can't be matched by merely being a tourist. You might still want to travel so you can use that place as a base to visit various destinations on your time off.

Southeast Asia has experienced tremendous growth in the last few years. Some of the biggest airplane orders are coming from there. Indonesia and Malaysia are looking for good pilots. Don't know if they provide training or not. Check out AirAsia and other regional airlines. Regional in this case means the Southeast Asia region and may be international.

Or the middle-east. Here's [Etihad training program](https://careers.etihad.com/Etihad/job/Abu-Dhabi-Cadet-Pilot-Programme-UAE-National-BachelorHigher-Diploma-holders/56566701/)

[This](http://www.askcaptainlim.com/becoming-a-pilot-pilot-68/1068-etihad-airways-cadet-pilot-program.html) suggests Etihad accepts non-residents for training.

Comment: The comments suggest that Etihad no longer accepts foreigners

Comment: Judging from the pilots I've had when flying with them (and what I've heard from others,) Cathay Pacific heavily recruits Western pilots. Every pilot I've had with them was American, British, or Australian, even though the airline is based in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to learn to fly and become an airline pilot within
>   about 3 years (let's say age 20-23), then immediately get employed as
>   an airline pilot and fly intercontinental routes (even as a co-pilot)?

Yes, but not in the US. You'll have to look overseas at airlines like Emirates/Qatar etc. for that.

---

Airline routes are offered by seniority; and pilots that have been with the airline a significant amount of years (I am talking 5+ at minimum) are given the longer routes.

In the US, where I have the most exposure to the flight training side - once you get your ATP (Airline Transport Pilot) and have acquired all the relevant type certifications - your entire purpose in life is to build up your hours as PIC (Pilot In Command) / PF (Pilot Flying).

You will be doing this on regional airlines, which may be contracted out to larger airlines. You may be flying an aircraft that's painted in United colors, but its actually a regional airline used on "feeder" routes to the larger hub airports. This is typically the case in the US (and Europe).

Or, you may be employed by an airline that has no international routes.

Outside of these areas - if you come to the Middle East, you may be flying international routes at the start of your career; simply because that's the only option - and you may be flying the long haul jets if that's all the airline has to offer.

For example, Emirates (the largest operator of 777 and the A380) flies international exclusively; and the majority of their routes are medium to long haul (greater than 3 hours flight time). You may have a chance to fly internationally, but on shorter routes like Dubai - Muscat, Dubai - Bahrain, Dubai - Kuwait (this is the shortest A380 flight by Emirates, and is used for crew training/familiarization).

Qatar Airways is similar - they use their short routes for crew familiarization and training on their newer aircraft. They flew their 777-200/300LR on the Doha - Kuwait - Doha circuit when they first got the aircraft (a route normally served by the A320); and the 787 on the Doha - Dubai - Doha circuit (again, normally served by the A320).

However, you may not have the opportunity to fly the longer routes until well into your career with the airline; and you will be starting off (training) in smaller aircraft and *a lot* of simulator time.

Typical training period for commercial pilots is between 3 and 4 years (if you are directly trained by an airline, such as Emirate's [flight training program](http://www.emiratesflighttrainingacademy.com/)) and then you are qualified as an airline pilot.

Comment: Actually, Southwest flies to Mexico, Jamaica, the Dominican Republic and Costa Rica, Belize, the Bahamas and Aruba. See [their map](https://www.southwest.com/travel_center/routemap_dyn.html).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yeah, international routes are a somewhat recent addition for Southwest. Many of them were added after they acquired AirTran Airlines, which already flew several routes to the Caribbean. Southwest doesn't have any long-haul, flights, though, as they only operate 737s.

Comment: How feasible is it to work on Middle Eastern routes with Emerates for people who don't speak Arabic?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the hard way to see the world.

Assuming you have a private license with complex and retractable endorsements. Then the next step is to get your instrument rating, multi engine, turbine and commercial ATR rating and at least 800 to a thousand hours as PIC (Pilot in Command). By now you have spend over $50,000 and might be employable as first officer for a small low budget commuter line at a couple of G's a month.

Is it worth it? That's up to you. I have over 4,000 hours in single and multi engine prop and jet aircraft. I own and fly a Beech Baron which is considered to be one of the more challenging light twin engine planes. I do not consider myself qualified to be an airline pilot.